# Schema.org 'reviewRating' not recognized by Google Rich Snippet Testing Tool

Tags: google-rich-snippets-tool, schema.org

I'm trying to add more structural information to my webpages by using the Microdata format with Schema.org. The procedure seems straight forward but I'm having issues validating my results in the Google Rich Snippets Testing Tool.

Check out this [review page](http://www.kettik.com/go/asia/india/ladakh/changthang/reviews/13), here I'm using the `reviewRating` property item to specify rating values for that particular review. I followed the same format as defined in [`Rating`](http://schema.org/Rating) but this markup fails validation in Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool with the following error info:

```
Item 
Type: http://schema.org/rating
reviewrating = 5 
ratingvalue = 5 
Warning: Property "reviewrating" was not found.
```

Comment: I would work on fixing your validation errors before worrying about Google - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kettik.com%2Fgo%2Fasia%2Findia%2Fladakh%2Fchangthang%2Freviews%2F13&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 4):

Ok, first of all you are **not** using the microformat suggested by www.schema.org. If you would, your markup code would look like this:

```
<span itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" style="display:none;">
<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">2</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
</div>
<div class="miniratingbox" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <div class="miniratingvalue blue" itemprop="bestRating">5</div>
      <div class="miniratingimg">★</div>
</div>
```

and instead of wrapping your complete "reviewContentWrapper" class with a wrong microdata format, you should specifically use the microdata where it belongs ... which in your case is totally unnecessary, since you already passed that information (with only two stars, see above) ...

```
<span class="rating-foreground" style="width:90%" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5">
    ★
    ★
    ★
    ★
    ★
</span>
```

Hope this helps!

For more information, please consult this page and read thoroughly: http://schema.org/Rating